# How do you make a backup in Amazon EC2 and Download it

Tags: backup, amazon-ec2

I have an instance in Amazon EC2 and contains Liferay Files, How do I create file a zip files of those files and download it? or is their a quicker process in creating a backup and download it? I've tried accessing the files via sFTP but its really slow when downloading the files one by one...

This is my first time managing a cloud host, please do advice.

Thank You.

Comment: What have you been using in that situation for non-cloud hosts. The same tools should work...

Comment: I'm using FileZilla in accessing the server. But in this approach, it's really slow. I've been downloading this for 2 days now and it's still haven't finish downloading. I have a download speed of 0.60 Mbps. I was hoping that Amazon provide a software that it will zip your directory so the download would be much faster and easier.

Comment: So just login to the server and zip the directory yourself before transmission?

Comment: @Server Horror, any guide how to do that? Do i do that inside Amazon EC2 or I can use Filezilla.

Comment: It depends on your operating system. EC2 offers linux and Windows. Honestly given the quality of your questions please consult professional help for managing servers which are out in the internet. No harm intended but you are asking to be hacked, as for guide: Your questions are that basic they really don't belong on serverfault

Comment: @Server Horror, Thanks. Anyways, i've manage to zip it using tar command and download it via ftp.

Comment: Yep, "tar -czvf file.tgz *" does a pretty good job of directory backup, then winscp file transfer for the win. It has download restart so it works well over connections with occasional flakeouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools that come to my mind:

- ssh (scp or sftp)
- rsync (over ssh or plain if the files aren't worth being encrypted)
- ftp/s
- http/s

Generaly managing a cloud host isn't different from a non-cloud host.